# What philosophy principles fit with "there is no reason, just position"?

Tags: truth, reason

One of the top authors in Asia, [Ni Kuang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ni_Kuang), mentioned, "I don't usually discuss religion or politics in public, because there is no 'reasons' -- there is only 'position'", meaning if you are in that camp, you will say that camp is correct or is the truth, no matter what.

What philosophy principles are related to this thinking?

Another example can be: an old novel was posted on the Internet and the novel was not popular at all. Some people claimed that the novelist's family should get some royalty, but somebody posted "My son in kindergarten taught me: Share, we share things". But I wouldn't be surprised if that person posted some rearranged piano music sheet on the Internet for some old songs for $2 a piece, and people posted his work for free on the Internet, he'd not claim "Share, we share", but he probably would say, "we should respect intellectual properties."

Comment: Search *perspectivism*...